# VCode push to Github only works for one folder and not 3 others

Tags: reactjs, git, visual-studio-code, gitignore

I have this in my .gitignore and the only think that's being ignored is node_modules.

```
# not adding folders
public/images/weeks
.history
.vscode
node_modules
```

I added a `git add .gitignore..` file and VCode aske me if I wanted to add the `node_modules` to the .gitignore file and I say yes. Then I added the other folders manually and commit changes.

What is it I do wrong when I push this to GitHub only `node_modules` is excluded?
Do I need to `git add..somefolder..` all stuff that need to be en the .gitignore

Comment: Only stuff you add to the commit gets pushed to Github. Looked at your git status before you commit and remove files from the index/stage you don't want and maybe add these to the `.gitignore`

Comment: Yea your right thanks